# Recover from error in any of multiple maps

Tags: scala

```
  println(
    Try(1)
      .map(doOne)
      .map(doTwo)
      .recover { 
          // this catches only errors from doTwo
          case e: Throwable => println("recovering from: " + e.getMessage) 
    }
  )

  def doOne(i: Int): Int = i + 1; throw new RuntimeException("failed in one")
  def doTwo(i: Int): Int = i + 2
```

How can a single `recover` catch any errors from preceeding maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would catch both error. Isn't your problem just that you forgot bracket in doOne?

That should be :

```
def doOne(i: Int): Int = { i + 1; throw new RuntimeException("failed in one")}
```

Otherwise, it just means

```
def doOne(i: Int) = i + 1

throw new RuntinmeException ...
```

The exception is thrown at the start of your program, completely outside Try.